# Appearance in Checkbox does not work

Tags: bugs, front-end, gui-construction, documentation

**Bug introduced in 8 and persisting through 11.2.0**

---

I'm experiencing strange behavior in `Checkbox` with `Appearance`:

```
Table[Checkbox[Appearance -> a], {a, {Tiny, Small, Medium, Large}}]
```

(Copied from the [help file](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Checkbox.html#1182586917)) doesn't give me any difference in size. Screenshot:

[image: checkbox sizes screenshot]

`CheckboxBar` has the same behavior. *Mathematica* seems to ignore the `Appearance` setting.

I'm running version 8.0.4.0 on Ubuntu 12.10 (64-bit).

**Question: Is this a bug or just a non-existing but nonetheless documented feature?**

Comment: I think `Checkbox` has only one appearance by design. At least I've never seen smaller or larger ones so far. Please only use the tag `bugs` if it is confirmed by WRI or the community.

Comment: Thanks for the edit in the tags. I thought "bugs" was for possible bugs too.

Comment: Changing the `Appearance` of `Checkbox` is documented, so Wolfram at least planned to add this functionality.
I think i remember seeing different sizes in mma on Windows but since even the online help file doesn't display different sizes i think the functionality does not exist at all.

Comment: It's in the tag-wiki. As to the question: I get the same on Windows. Perhaps it's different on MacOS? Anyway, I can imagine that this feature was implemented to make use of (future) OS-specific GUI options. BTW I know an A.Goossens, but you don't happen to be that AF guy, do you?

Comment: "AF" doesn't ring a bell, sorry...

Comment: AF stands for Air force

Comment: No wings here, unfortunately.

Comment: @IstvánZachar: this is a bug, regardless of what WRI says. It's an objective statement that they claim in the help file that you can change the size with the Appearance option, which doesn't work, in objective reality. That's a bug, all right, not a matter of opinion. It's not like WRI is the pope and we're all hard core catholic or something.

Comment: @mathheadinclouds In the last 7 years, we all recognized that :)

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be system dependent.  With version 7 under Windows 7 I get:

[image: Mathematica graphics]  (150% magnification)

Comment: Definitely a regression in version 8, then. Oddly I find (again, in version 7 on Windows 7) that they appear correctly at 100% but going to 150% or larger the size difference disappears.

Comment: changing the magnification seems to occasionally cause strange behaviour in dynamics

Answer (score 4):

I evaluated

```
Table[Checkbox[Appearance -> a], {a, {Tiny, Small, Medium, Large}}]
```

It worked on my system.

[image: checkbox sequence]

Answer (score 4):

This bug still persists in Windows Mathematica 11.x.0 for x>=2
However, there is hope it will be fixed soon, since on the cloud it seems to work:
[image]

Comment: Good to know it works on cloud but I don't think there is any hope. This is completely different front end, they did conversion properly in this case.

Comment: There is always hope. Shouldn't this post deserve the bugs tag?

Comment: Ok, there is always hope but I think it is independent from the fact it works on cloud. I think so, tagged.

Comment: Using macOS 10.13 and MMA 11.2, `Medium`and `Large` give the same size