# How to make the size of a control object larger/smaller?

Tags: gui-construction, wolfram-cloud

I currently have a form with a picture label,

```
FormFunction[{"mm" -> <| "Label" :> [[**Insert Picture here**]] , 
"Interpreter" -> "Boolean"|>}, 
Identity][]
```

and I end up with:

[image]

How can I increase the size of the check box to better match the size of the picture?

As an added layer of complexity I plan on **CloudDeploying** this 
form.

Answer (score 2):

Specify a control:

```
 FormFunction[{"mm" -> <|
      "Label" -> labelimage,
      "Interpreter" -> "Boolean",
      "Control" -> 
            Function[Toggler[#,
                {True -> checkimage, False -> uncheckimage},
                uncheckimage]]
      |>}][]
```

Comment: nice, cool solution- but using this approach, I would lose some of the native advantages of the checkbox- i.e. hover and tabbed use.

Comment: OK, but Checkbox doesn't seem to give much of a size selection: `Table[Checkbox[True, 
  Appearance -> a], {a, {Tiny, Small, Medium, Large}}]`

Comment: @ChristopherHaydock, this problem has been discussed [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15132/appearance-in-checkbox-does-not-work)

Comment: @garej thank you for the reference!